# Almost Sure convergence for sequence of random variables

Tags: random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables converging to $X$ almost surely. $f:{\rm I\!R} \to {\rm I\!R}$ is a continuous function. Then, $f(X_n)$ converges to $f(X)$ almost surely.

Comment: This should follow from the definition of continuity.

Comment: You are welcome. But do you understand how it follows? That is, can you write down a proof of this fact?

Answer (score 4):

I need to show that  $P\{ w:f(X_n)(w) \to f(X)(w)\} = 1$

I know that  $P\{ w:X_n(w) \to X(w)\} = 1$

Let $w$ be such that $X_n(w)\to X(w)$

Then because $f$ is continuous $f(X_n(w))\to f(X(w))$

so $\{ w:X_n(w) \to X(w)\}$  $\subseteq$   $\{ w:f(X_n)(w) \to f(X)(w)\}$

The smaller set has probability 1 so the bigger set must also have probability 1.

Comment: @ actoh binna I think I got it right. Please let me know if there is some more arguements that need to be considered.

Comment: I am also considering a similar problem where everything is same as in this question only the convergence is in probability.